# Query past the 500 limit in Gerrit REST API

Tags: java, gerrit

I'm trying to get 2000 change results from a specific branch with a query request using Gerrit REST API in Java. The problem is that I'm only getting 500 results no matter what I add to the query search.

I have tried the options listed [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#_search_operators) but I'm not getting the 2000 results that I need.  I also read that [an admin can increase this limit](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/access-control.html#capability_queryLimit) but would prefer a method that doesn't require this detour.
So what I'm wondering is:

1. Is it possible to increase the limit without the need to contact the admin?
2. If not. Is it possible to continue/repeat the query in order to get the remaining 1500 results that I want, using a loop that performs the query on the following 500 results from the previous query until I finally get 2000 results in total?

Comment: I have implemented a crawler in Python. Let me know if this helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

When using the [list changes REST API](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes), the results are returned as a list of [ChangeInfo Elements](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#change-info).  If there are more results than were returned, the last entry in that list will have a `_more_changes` field with value `true`.  You can then query again and set the `start` option to skip over the ones that you've already received.

Comment: The API still blocks for more than 500 entries.

Comment: Right, it will limit the result to 500 entries per query.  If there are more than 500 results you have to do multiple queries using the `start` option.

Comment: Try to call this one `https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/status:open,10000` and you will see what I mean. :-)

Comment: That doesn't work at all, it just returns the HTML of the review site.

Try something like:

  `curl https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=status:open`which will return 500 results, and then `curl "https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=status:open&S=501"` which will return the next 500.

Comment: Same here, if I go with `curl "https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=status:open&S=10000"`, I got the following error message: `cannot exceed 10000 results (after filtering for visibility)`. So we were both right: 500 is not the limit, but still `S` (pagination) has its limits, too. :)

Comment: OK, it seems we were talking about slightly different things.  FWIW I think the `cannot exceed 10000 results (after filtering for visibility)` error is something specific to Google's internal version of Gerrit; that error message does not exist in the open source version.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add a minor workaround to [David's great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45305243/1864294).

If you want to crawl Gerrit instances hosted on Google servers (such as Android, Chromium, Golang), you will notice that they block queries with more than 10000 results. You can check this e.g. with

```
curl "https://android-review.googlesource.com/changes/?q=status:closed&S=10000"
```

I solved the problem in such a way, that I split up these list of changes with [`before:` and `until:`](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-search.html#before_until) in a query string, for example lie

```
_url_/changes/?q=after:{2018-01-01 00:00:00.000} AND before:{2018-01-01 00:59:99.999}
_url_/changes/?q=after:{2018-01-01 01:00:00.000} AND before:{2018-01-01 01:59:99.999}
_url_/changes/?q=after:{2018-01-01 02:00:00.000} AND before:{2018-01-01 02:59:99.999}
```

and so on. I think you get the idea. ;-) Please notice, that both limits (`before:` and `after:`) are inclusive! For each day I use the pagination described by David.

A nice side effect is, that you can track the progress of the crawling.

I wrote a small [Python tool named "Gerry"](https://github.com/michaeldorner/Gerry) to crawl open source instances. Feel free to use, adopt it and send me pull requests!

Answer (score -2):

I almost had the same problem. But there is no way as you mentioned you don't want admin to increase the query limit and also you don't want to fire the rest query in a loop with the counter. I will suggest you to follow the second approach firing the query in a loop with a counter set. That's the way I have implemented the rest client in Java.